# print() not a member of class?

Tags: c++, function, class, printing, program-entry-point

I am trying to run a getter/setter code in C++ Visual Studio 2008 and have my header file, implementation file and main file. In the main, there is a print function (`P1.print();`) which tries to print the class object `P1`. I get error of `print()` not a member of Persontype. When I declare void `print();` in header, I get 3 errors -----

```
Persontest.obj : error LNK2005: _main already defined in proj1.obj -----
Persontest.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall  
Persontype::print(void)" (?print@Persontype@@QAEXXZ) referenced in function _main ----- fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals.
```

Can someone pls help me resolve this issue?

Persontype.h(header file):

```
#ifndef H_Persontype
#define H_Persontype

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



class Persontype{

public:
Persontype();

Persontype(string fn, string mn, string ln, char g);

//setter
void setfirstName(string fn);
void setmiddleName(string mn);
void setlastName(string ln);
void setGender(char g);

//getter
string getfirstName() const;
string getlastName() const;
string getmiddleName() const;
char getGender() const;

private:
string firstName;
string middleName;
string lastName;
char gender;


};

#endif/
```

Person.cpp(implementation file):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "Persontype.h"
using namespace std;






//default constructor
Persontype::Persontype()
{
firstName = "Me";
middleName = "My";
lastName = "Mine";
gender = 'X';
}

//specific constructor
Persontype::Persontype(string fn, string mn, string ln, char g){
firstName = fn;
middleName = mn;
lastName = ln;
gender = g;
}

//setters
void Persontype::setfirstName(string fn)
{
firstName = fn;
}

void Persontype::setmiddleName(string mn)
{
middleName = mn;
}

void Persontype::setlastName(string ln)
{
lastName = ln;
}

void Persontype::setGender(char g)
{
gender = g;
}

//getters
string Persontype::getfirstName () const
{
   return firstName;
}

string Persontype::getmiddleName () const
{
   return middleName;
}

string Persontype::getlastName () const
{
   return lastName;
}

char Persontype::getGender() const
{
return gender;
}
```

Persontest.cpp(main file):

```
#include "Persontype.h"

int main(){

Persontype P1("tom","smith","alice",'m');

P1.print();
}
```

Comment: Well the error message couldn't really be any clearer - you don't have a method called `print()`, i.e. you need to implement `Persontype::print()`.

Comment: Pass strings to functions by const reference. You can even return them by const reference if they are a member of the class.

Answer (score 1):

You, of course, need to *both* declare it in the `Persontype` class declaration in the header:

```
void print() const;
```

and define it in the .cpp file:

```
void Persontype::print(void) const
{
  cout << "My name is " << getfirstName() << ", I live on the second floor\n";
}
```

The errors about multiple `main()` have nothing to do with `print()`, that's some other error you're doing either in code which you're not showing or in how you build your program.

Comment: i tried as above in .cpp - ERROR. one or more multiply symbols found and main already defined in abc.obj???